# Firebase redirect only base URL

Tags: regex, firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

My goal is to redirect the base URL (mydomain.com/) to a different website.
I am using Firebase Hosting and already tried the Regex function in redirect to achieve this. I followed this firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=de) on redirects without success.

My Goal:

- mydomain.com/ => otherdomain.com
- mydomain.com/#any => mydomain.com/#any

I found that this can be achieved in JavaScript with but because im new to Firebase I am not sure how I can use this. (maybe by using Cloud Function?)

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
  //redirect to otherdomain.com
}
```

My Code:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "redirects": [
      {
        "regex": "^/$",
        "destination": "otherdomain.com",
        "type": 301
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Problem, this code redirects every URL to the new domain.
My next idea was to use `"regex": "^(?!.*[/].+)"` but it `?!` is not supported.

Comment: Try `"regex": "^[^/]*$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not redirecting

Comment: Then `^(?!.*[/].+)` is a wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this. I do know that a lot of domain registrars allow you to do this. Open your domain registrar, and set a URL redirect or URL Forward, and set it to use the same URL path. If this is not an option in your domain registrar, you might want to check out google domains. https://domains.google.com. I know that registrar allows you to do this, I have done it before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found an option to forward my Domain in my DNS settings but this still doesn't allow me to redirect ONLY the base URL and not everything.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
`firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

`index.html`

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    if(window.location.href === "mydomain.com/") {
      window.location.href = "www.otherdomain.com";
    }
  </script>
  ...
</body>
```

add `https://` in front of `mydomain.com/` and  `www.otherdomain.com`